# AppCmd add AppPool Identity

Tags: appcmd

I am not able to find any document which describes how to set App Pool Identity to Specific user and provide username/password. I can do this for sites by following. I am looking for similar command to set App Pool Identity as specific user. Thanks.

```
appcmd.exe set config  -section:system.applicationHost/sites /[name='myappname'].[path='/'].[path='/'].userName:user /[name='catalog'].[path='/'].[path='/'].password:password  /commit:apphost
```